# Reputation tab shows -1 when I undownvoted an answer

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

I had downvoted an answer some days ago because it wasn't correct. I also commented what was wrong in the answer. Then after 2 days,OP corrected his mistake and said "Thanks!" to me.

I removed the downvote and a "+1" came in the icon in the toolbar at the top. But when I looked at my user page,it showed "-1" at the reputation tab instead of showing "+1". See the below screenshot to see it. I think this is a small bug and needs to be fixed.

[image: -1 at the reputation tab while +1 at the toolbar]

Comment: maybe a caching issue?